# A* pathfinding AI object moves towards a moving target Unity

Tags: c#, a-star

I am trying to make an AI object to chase my player. The player is controlled by the user.

This is the code that I have so far for the AI when the target is in a fixed position not moving. How can I change it to make my AI object chase my player?

```
public class AstarAI : MonoBehaviour
{

    //The point to move to
    public Transform target;

    private Seeker seeker;

    //The calculated path
    public Path path;

    //The AI's speed per second
    public float speed = 2;

    //The max distance from the AI to a waypoint for it to continue to the next waypoint
    public float nextWaypointDistance = 3;

    //The waypoint we are currently moving towards
    public int currentWaypoint = 0;


    public bool arrived;

    public void Start()
    {
       seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
       arrived = false;    
       seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);

    }



    public void OnPathComplete(Path p)
    {
        Debug.Log("Path calculated? " + p.error);
        if (!p.error)
        {
            path = p;
            //Reset the waypoint counter
            currentWaypoint = 0;
        }
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {


        if (path == null)
        {
            //We have no path to move after yet
            return;
        }

        if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
        {
            Debug.Log("End Of Path Reached");
            arrived = true;
            return;
        }

        //Direction to the next waypoint
        Vector3 dir = (path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position).normalized;
        dir *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        this.gameObject.transform.Translate(dir);

        //Check if we are close enough to the next waypoint

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]) < nextWaypointDistance)
        {
            currentWaypoint++;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently as your question stands it's a bit difficult for a reader to understand how you're approaching the problem. And show us how you've attempted to solve the problem yourself, so we can provide feedback.

Comment: Basically you need every X interval to check if the target you are following has moved. If it has moved then recalculate a path to the target, probably here you can also check if some waypoints (one-two close to the AI) are already the same with the recalculated one so you can keep moving towards them and then replace the next ones to the updated location until eventually it will reach the target.
Does this sound close enough to what you are looking for?

Comment: I added this code   public void GetNewPath()
    {
        seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        GetNewPath();
    }

Comment: @S.Fragkos yes basically that is what I am looking for. Can you give me some snippets of code please because I am new to this and am finding it hard to code it.

Comment: @ladyBug I'm at work now so dont have much time to write it start from the easy parts and I'll help you later if you havent completed it!

Comment: @ladyBug if you add new code, add it _into the question_, not as comment. And if you _do_ mention code in comments for some reason, surround it by `. See the "help" link under the big "Add Comment" button for formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recompute the route in the Update, like you suggested in you comment:

```
public void Update() 
{ 
    GetNewPath(); 
}
```

However this might put a big load on your machine if there are lots of possible path to search.
I suggest that you call a function that updates less often. Here is an example that recompute the path every seconds:

```
private const float _tickInterval = 1f 

public void Start()
{
    // your code
    // ...

    StartCoroutine(AiTick);
}

public IEnumerator AiTick();
{
    while(true)
    {
        seeker.GetNewPath(); 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_tickInterval);
    }
}

public void OnDestroy()
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
}
```

In this example, you don't need an `Update` function. Instead we use a **coroutine**. Coroutines are functions that can stop executing, and resume later, using the yield keyword. See the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for more info.

Here it works as follow:

- The `public IEnumerator AiTick();` is the coroutine. Its execution can be delayed using `yield`
- In `Start` we call 'StartCoroutine(AiTick);', this is the same as calling the `AiTick()` function, but allows it to be used as a coroutine
- The AiTick function will call `seeker.GetNewPath()`, then **stop for `_tickInterval` seconds**. When it resumes latter, if will reach the end of the loop, go back at the start of the while and call `seeker.GetNewPath` again, replacing the Update function but executing only once every `_tickInterval`seconds
- In `OnDestroy` we stop the coroutine, since it never exits. We don't need to do it since the object is destroyed anyway but this is cleaner

Comment: still not working. 'private const float tickInterval = f' is giving me an error even the GetNewPath.

Comment: I did some modifications because of errors
   ` public void Start()
    {
       seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
       arrived = false;    
       seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);
        AiTick();
        
      
    }
    public IEnumerator AiTick()
{
    
         seeker.GetNewPath(transform.position, target.position);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_tickInterval);

}

public void OnDestroy()
{
    StopAllCoroutines();
}
    public void Update()
    {
        seeker.GetNewPath(transform.position, target.position);
    }`

Comment: Better to edit your question adding the new code in the bottom instead of putting in comment. Apparently you didn't quite understand what I was suggesting. **First:** In my example, you don't have an Update function. That is the whole point of the coroutine. **Second** In the Start method, you have to call the coroutine with `StartCoroutine(AiTick);` **Third:** if you remove the while loop in the coroutine, the coroutine become useless. I'll edit my answer to explain what coroutines are